# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Tags: appium

```
public class Mobiletest {
    private static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException,
            InterruptedException {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi 1s");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.4");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        // capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage",
                "com.zipgo.customer");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",
                "SplashActivity");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
                capabilities);          

        // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

It gives error as below don't where it is going wrong

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'INSPIRON', ip: '192.168.1.35', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
>   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver

Answer (score 0):

do you have multiple appium instances running? If not try to change port from 4723 to something else.

Comment: note that appium is needed to start manually before running tests

Comment: any other port means 4722,4724 any ,and i has started the appium server manually by clicking the play symbol,and also once changed the port number to 4728 it showed on the appium port number 4728 on appium but when i run the Eclipse script it showed me the result on 4723 port

Comment: did you change the port to same in android driver  and appium settings

Comment: appium setting i had changed ,in the android driver where u can change

Answer (score 0):

[image]

first in appium  UI

then in code

```
 driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
            capabilities);
```

Just like in your example code

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'INSPIRON', ip: '192.168.